# What is the type of a ternary expression with int and char operands?

Tags: java, char

I recently come accross the scenario where in first syso() charcter is working fine but in second syso() it is printing ASCII code.

```
public class Test{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char x = 'A';
    char y= 'B';
    int m = 0;

    System.out.println(true  ? x : 0);//Working fine prints A
    System.out.println(true  ? y : 0);//Working fine prints B
    System.out.println(false ? 0 : y);//Working fine prints B
    System.out.println(false ? m : x);// Here it prints 65 why ?
   }
 }
```

I really want to know why it is printing ascii code in second syso() ? Please help

Comment: i just edited my code and put 0 in front but answer is again contradicting our hypothesis.

Comment: @Sotirios Doh. I sat here looking through the JLS instead of looking for dupes.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in the type of `false ? m : x`, which ends up being `int`, not `char`.

As per [JLS section 15.25.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25.2) (emphasis and [] note mine):

> The type of a numeric conditional expression is determined as follows:
>
> - If the second and third operands have the same type, then that is the type of the conditional expression.
>
> ...
>
> - Otherwise [if none of the above rules hold], **binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is applied to the operand types, and the type of the conditional expression is the promoted type of the second and third operands.**

Where [binary numeric promotion's relevant rule is](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) (emphasis mine):

> Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
> - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
> - **Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.**

Therefore in:

```
char x = ...;
int m = ...;
```

The expression `condition ? m : x` is promoted to `int`, and [`System.out.println(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println-int-) is called, and it prints it as a number.

You'd have to explicitly cast `m` or the whole expression to a `char`, e.g.:

```
System.out.println((char)(false ? m : x));
```

Or:

```
System.out.println(false ? (char)m : x);
```

As for your `condition ? x : 0` and `condition ? 0 : x` forms, one of the rules (that I omitted above) from 15.25.2 is:

> - If one of the operands is of type T where T is byte, short, or char, and the other operand is a constant expression (§15.28) of type int whose value is representable in type T, then the type of the conditional expression is T.

0 fits this description. `x` is a `char`, 0 fits in a `char`, the type of the conditional is therefore `char` and the character is printed.

Comment: Why it is not working once we have 0 infront instead of m

Comment: @ShowStopper See my edit, end of the answer.